# Utilizar addEventListener Click en javascript

Tags: php, javascript, click

No tengo ni la mas mínima idea de javascript, pero estuve investigando y llegue a la conclusión de que para hacer mi buscador de php lo iba a necesitar entonces encontré un código que me funciona a la perfección, el buscador es en tiempo real, y eso es un inconveniente para mi, porque mi buscador busca imágenes y por lo tanto se tarda demasiado en cargar, así que mi pregunta es que si alguien sabe como agregar la condición de que solo se ejecute la búsqueda al darle click, o que me pueda explicar más a fondo el funcionamiento de mi script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search').focus()

  $('#search').on('keyup', function(){
    var search = $('#search').val()
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php/search.php',
      data: {'search': search},
      beforeSend: function(){
        $('#result').html('<img src="img/pacman.gif">')
      }
    })
    .done(function(resultado){
      $('#result').html(resultado)
    })
    .fail(function(){
      alert('Hubo un error :(')
    })
  })
})
```

----CODIGO DE MI INDEX-----

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Buscador PHP</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos__buscador.css">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header text-left">
    <h1>Buscador             <small>              Registro  </small></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="BuscA">
        <input type="submit" value="realizar busqueda" id="button" name="button">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3" id="result">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Olvide añadir que utilizo ajax

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es cambiar tu handler para que no escuche el evento `keyup` de tu input `search` sino que escuche el evento `click` en tu boton `button`.  Quedaria asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search').focus()

  $('#button').on('click', function(){
    var search = $('#search').val()
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php/search.php',
      data: {'search': search},
      beforeSend: function(){
        $('#result').html('<img src="img/pacman.gif">')
      }
    })
    .done(function(resultado){
      $('#result').html(resultado)
    })
    .fail(function(){
      alert('Hubo un error :(')
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Buscador PHP</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos__buscador.css">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header text-left">
    <h1>Buscador             <small>              Registro  </small></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="BuscA">
        <input type="submit" value="realizar busqueda" id="button" name="button">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3" id="result">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: ya lo puse como me dijiste y no me funciona :(

Comment: Como puedes ver aqui si funciona.  Puedes intentar esto: `$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {`

Answer (score 1):

Esto va a buscar por cada vez q levantes la tecla q tiene apretada. Es porque pusiste el `keyup` a tu barra de busqueda:

```
$('#search').on('keyup', function(){
```

Si quieres mantener tu manera de buscar pero que no te busque por cada vez que apretes una tecla, puedes cambiarlo por `change` y solo buscara cuando el valor cambie

```
$('#search').on('change', function(){
```

Comment: Si quieres que cambie cuando apretes el boton `buscar`, usa la [respuesta de alanfcm](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/258489/60415)

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: No hay porque. Recuerda que si alguna de las respuestas soluciona tu problema, marcala como correcta.

Comment: Sip, pero aun no resuelvo mi duda :c, ya probe lo de alanfcm y no me funciono

Comment: Cual es el error? Lo hiciste todo como el dice?

Comment: Si, deje mi fragmento de codigo asi

  $('#button').on('click', function(){

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92881/discussion-between-manuco-bianco-and-jesus).

Comment: Gracias de antemano a todos los que me ayudaron, al ultimo el error por el que no funcionaba era porque mi archivo js esta ejecutando el cache, y lo que hice fue agregar al sourc de mi js esto (src="mi archivo.js?1")

Answer (score 1):

Vale, comienzo explicandote de una forma general lo que hace tu código, pero antes de ello, te aclaro que lo que estás usando no es **JavaScript** puro netamente, lo que estás usando es **JQuery**, que básicamente es una librería o extensión de JavaScript que permite acceder a los elementos del DOM y otras funcionalidades de JavaScript, pero con sintaxis más simplificada y a mi parecer, más sencilla.

- Primeramente, `$(document).ready()`, lo que hace es ejecutar cualquier cosa una vez haya cargado la página por completo y sus respectivos componentes.
- Luego `$('#search').focus()`, lo que hace es poner el cursor en tu caja de búsqueda
- Con `$('#search').on('keyup')`, lo que haces es ejecutar alguna función una vez escribas algo en tu caja de búsqueda.
- Con `$('#search').val()`, obtienes el valor de lo que estás escribiendo en tu caja de búsqueda.
- Y por último, con `$.ajax({..})`, lo que haces es hacer una petición a un archivo externo, que será el que hará la interacción con la BD para obtener los datos de la consulta respecto al valor ingresado en la caja de búsqueda.

Para acceder a los elementos, es parecido a `css`, es decir, para acceder a las propiedades **id**, se usa `$('#elemento')`, para acceder a propiedades **class**, se usa `$('.elemento')`.

Ahora, teniendo en cuenta todo esto, te dejo dos ejemplos en los que activas o ejecutas funciones con dos eventos, el `keyup` y el `click`, por ello, podrás cambiar

```
$('#search').on('keyup', function(){...}),
```

por

```
$('#search').on('click', function(){...})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Asociamos evento keyup para ejecutar función al momento de escribir
  $('#search-Keyup').on('keyup', function (){
    //Obtenemos el valor escrito
    let valorInputKeyup = $('#search-Keyup').val();
    
    //Cargamos el valor escrito en la etiqueta <p>
    $('#mostrarContenidoKeyup').text(valorInputKeyup);
    
  });
  
  //Asociamos evento click al enlace para ejecutar función al momento de clickear sobre él
  $('#search-Click').on('click', function (){
    
    //Obtenemos el valor escrito
    let valorInputClick = $('#search-ClickInput').val();
    
    //Cargamos el valor escrito a la segunda etiqueta <p>
    $('#mostrarContenidoClick').text(valorInputClick);
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="search-Keyup">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" id="search-ClickInput">
  <a id="search-Click" href="#">Haz click</a>
</div>

<br><br>

<h6>Keyup: <p id="mostrarContenidoKeyup"></p></h6>
<br>
<h6>Click: <p id="mostrarContenidoClick"></p></h6>
```

Comment: Muy bien explicado gracias, me sirvio mucho :D

Comment: Ok @Jesús, me alegra haber contribuido en algo, y espero que haya logrado de alguna manera solucionar su problema.